# Deleting linked objects

Tags: c++, class, object, linked-list

I have two classes: "node" and "poly".  The node objects are linked together to form a linked list.  The poly object holds a pointer to the first node.  I am trying to deallocate the memory for the entire "poly".  I want to delete the poly - then within the poly destructor call a function (something like "freePoly") that will help me iterate through the entire linked list of node objects - deleting all nodes.

Here is the class definition:

```
class Node
{
private:
double coeff;
int exponent;
Node *next;
public:

Node(double c, int e, Node *nodeobjectPtr)
{
    coeff = c;
    exponent = e;
    next = nodeobjectPtr;
}

~Node()
{
     printf("Node Destroyed");
      //???
}
class poly
{
private:
Node *start;
public:
poly(Node *head)  /*constructor function*/
{
    start = head;
}
~poly() /*destructor*/
{
       //???
}

void freePoly();
};

void poly::freePoly()
{
 //???
}
```

I've tried a lot of things, but essentially I get stuck where I'm only deleting the first node object.  Then I've lost the pointer to the other nodes... and leak memory because I can't access them anymore for deletion.

Comment: Didn't you ask this here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200451/using-the-destructor-to-free-linked-objects

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid a lot of problems and work by using a `std::vector` instead of a Do-It-Yourself linked list. Unless this is for learning.

That said, do

```
~poly() /*destructor*/
{
    while( start != 0 )
    {
        node* p_doomed = start;
        start = start->next;
        delete p_doomed;
    }
}
```

There are also many other ways to do this, but the above is a pattern that can help you figure out how to do similar things.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your code as is, then your `freePoly` should look like this:

```
while(start)
{
    Node *ptr = start;
    start = start->getNext();
    delete ptr;
}
```

Notice what this code does: first it makes a copy of the pointer to the current head - i.e. the first `Node`, then it makes head point to the next object and only *then* calls `delete` for the *old* head pointer.

Of course, this design isn't ideal: you are programming using a C++ compiler and you have some classes and some member functions but you aren't really *using* C++ effectively:

Not only does language provides you with wonderful tools such as `std::list` or `std::vector` so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel and things like `std::unique_ptr` so that pointers know when it's safe to delete themselves.

It also provides you with powerful abstract concepts to model the bahavior of objects.

I suggest that you take a step back and rethink your code. Key questions to ask are: how can I write less code here? What facilities of C++ can I leverage here? What are these objects I have and what does each object do?

I understand that this may be a homework exercise and you have to implement things a certain way, but don't let that stop you from learning.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
private:
   void auxDestroy(Node* p);


void Node::auxDestroy(Node* p){
   if (p!=0) {
      if (p->next != 0) {
         auxDestroy(p->next);
      }
      else {
            delete p;
      }
   }
}
```

Then in the destroy method you could call this auxDestroy(this->next);

```
~Node(){
    auxDestroy(this->next);
}
```

And in poly destructor:

```
~poly(){
   delete this->start;
}
```